# What is “medico-media material”?

Tags: meaning

Today I ran into the phrase *medico-media material*, and I don't know what it means. I tried to look it up on Google, but have had no luck so far.

It comes from a 2005 [letter to the editor](http://www.theage.com.au/news/Letters/The-unasked-million-dollar-question/2005/02/20/1108834657104.html) in *The Age* (Melbourne) regarding organ donation:

> In the last few years we have been subjected to a barrage of **medico-media material** that chides Australians for our low donation rates and implies consent to donation is the only morally or socially correct decision

Comment: What was the subject of the text the paragraph is from?

Comment: I imagine *medico-media material* just means *coverage of medical matters in the popular media* (newspapers, magazines, podcasts, etc.). What the passage is saying is that the Australian media consistently tries to promote the cause of organ donation by "shaming" their readers/audience into giving consent (or assuming it, in the case of deceased relatives who made no such declaration of intent during their lifetime).

Comment: No luck? [Google](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=medico%20media) shows quite some resuls for *'Medico Media'*, all suggesting that it's a company. [This](http://www.theage.com.au/news/Letters/The-unasked-million-dollar-question/2005/02/20/1108834657104.html) is the source of your quote, and [this](http://www.medico-media.net) the company it seems to refer to.

Comment: @Terah I'm assuming the OP found this reference but it's clearly not a reference to the company in the quoted paragraph; the company is in India but the article is about Australians, and it's not capitalised.

Comment: @John Clifford - Assumably so, however, Google seems to provide enough context to conclude that 'medico-media material' is not so much an existing phrase in English as that it is somehow used to refer to Medico-Media. With an article that is 11 years old however, I can imagine it being harder to find solid proof of this.

Comment: @Terah I acknowledge the possibility of a link, but the fact that I can find nothing on Google linking Medico Media to anything controversial regarding organ donation says to me that the person writing the letter was just coining a phrase with the meaning FumbleFingers imagined.

Comment: @John Clifford - I think the controversy bit concerned the movies, and how its audiences failed to recognise how disabled people might be offended by them. I'm not reading anything about controversy surrounding organ donation as such. FF might be quite right, but with the article being as old as it is, and the phrase having to have come from somewhere..(as in, Medico Media might have been engaged in some guilt tripping in a period prior to 2005), I'm not ruling anything out. I'll keep digging, now that my curiosity is piqued.

Comment: @Terah I'm curious too, looking forward to seeing what you come up with.

Comment: I should have realized this earlier, but the quoted text is provided by a single reader of 'The Age', not a journalist or author (which might explain the non-capitalization). I was thinking about contacting 'The Age', but I can imagine them having a hard time guessing as to what one of their readers is referring to. However, the reader that provided the quote is a (senior) medical professional, and for her, an e-mail address is publicly available, so let's see what she remembers about that letter :)

Comment: "Thank you for your email. I am out of the office with training committments until Tuesday March 15. i will respond to your email as soon as I can.
 
Please note my work days are Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday only.
"  Don't go anywhere people, we'll tackle this mystery yet!

Comment: Sidenote: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/medico?s=t) mentions: Medico- 1) a combining form representing medical, in compound words: medicolegal. (ie. what FF said, but now with 'proof' :P)

Comment: @JohnClifford The topic is about `Organ Donation`
@Terah I'm sure it's not related to a company's name, and just like you, I couldn't find it on Google except for that company :(

Comment: I know the topic is about organ donation; I think you misunderstood my point. I was saying that I couldn't find anything linking the *company* called Medico Media with the topic, not that the topic wasn't about organ donation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writers, and especially irate persons writing letters to the editor, are known to create new combinations of words in an attempt to convey their sentiments.  'Medico-media' may not be featured in the dictionary, but its constituent parts are:

> [**medico**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medico) (n.)  physician; also: a medical student
>
> 'She proved the medicos wrong by recovering quickly from her injuries.'
>
> 'a woman who is suspicious of all medicos, regardless of their credentials'
>
> **[medico-](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/medico-)** (combining form)  medical:  medical and

The word entered English in the 1680s, either from Italian or Spanish, and [medico-legal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=medico) came along as an adjective in 1835.

So at the very least, the writer is bemoaning a seemingly violent assault (barrage) of media material propagated by medical professionals. However, the example sentences in M-W's definition suggest that this use of 'medico' may also convey a contempt for such physicians.

Consider the telling case of '[Wacko Jacko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgsheS3YZ3s)', Javier Bardem's delivery of '[friendo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLCL6OYbSTw)' in the film 'No Country for Old Men', or the classic [Dumbo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfknSW_G-ic).

The pejorative use of 'o' is said to be even more common in Australian English than it is in the US, and while it is almost universally a bisyllabic construction in other countries, Australians are known to make exceptions for words such as 'rabbitohs'.  **O-ism** has in fact been reported in multiple languages.

*Source: Mikael Parkvall, [**O-words: colloquial/slangy words ending in <-o>**](https://linguistlist.org/issues/9/9-360.html) at linguistlist.org*